# oracle.jbo.NoDefException: JBO-25002: Definition Model.VOAPP of type ApplicationModule is not found

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, facelets

I am trying to call a Oracle stored procedure from AM`(Appmodule)`. It's working fine when I run my app on integrated `WLS`, but when I deploy my app on standalone `WLS` it say's:

> javax.faces.FacesException: #{LoginPageName.doLogin}: /Login.jsf @36,364 action="#{LoginPageName.doLogin}": oracle.jbo.NoDefException: JBO-25002: Definition Model.VOAPP of type ApplicationModule is not found.
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>           at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1243)
>           at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeInvokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:686)
>           at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:364)
>           at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:227)
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
>           at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$3.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:172)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:110)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilterInternal(JpsAbsFilter.java:273)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:147)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
>           at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
>           at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
>           at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
>           at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
>           at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
>           at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
>           at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
>           at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
>           at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>           at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)